# One thread suspending

Tags: c#, multithreading

I start to learn about threading and I wrote this code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread DoAction = new Thread(StartAction);
    DoAction.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Thread: {0}", i);
        if (i == 10000) DoAction.Suspend();
    }
}

static void StartAction()
{
    for(int i=0;i<int.MaxValue;++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

When i==10000 my application stopped. I want to suspend only DoAction Thread

Comment: This is an obsolete API that you shouldn't be using. I suggest you would spend your time more profitably looking into the APIs which *haven't* been deprecated - or better yet, higher level abstractions like tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I follow your advice

Comment: You can use this kind of code to gain some understanding of threading in general (this question being a good case in point) but Jon is right, none of this should show up in production code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Console is a 'thread-safe' class meaning that acces is regulated internally with locks.

With a little (bad) luck you will suspend the worker thread in the middle of a `WriteLine()`. 
Your main thread is then put on hold when it tries to write, and you're deadlocked.

Answer (score 3):

`Thread.Suspend` is almost always unsafe. Here, you probably suspend the entire console. Imagine you'd have suspended the static constructor of `system.string` (by accident). The entire `AppDomain` would come to a halt quickly.

Use some other means to synchronize your threads.

Comment: I would expect such a special constructor to be treated specially (as a protected region or something). But your point stands.